# SQL CASE WHEN issue?

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to complete [a tutorial on SQL JOIN](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation) (part 13) and not quite getting one query quite right. The two rows with no goals scored do not get returned in the results. I didn't expect this.

I joined the two tables appropriately (I think), then used a SUM() of a CASE WHEN statement to get the total number of soccer goals scored from the `goals` table.

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
  team2,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
  FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id
  GROUP BY id, mdate, team1, team2
  ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

My query works great **except** for the two rows with zero goals scored. What am I missing to make them show up as well?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no goals in the match, there will be no rows in `goal` with that `matchid`, so your `JOIN` will return 0 rows for that match. Change the `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` and you will get those rows from `game` with `NULL` values for each column in `goal`.